# Traceback Error while FBX export

Tags: export, error, .fbx

help I cant export this into a FBX file, an advance thank you to all who tried to help

[image: here is the error]

This is just a model, no Animations or Armatures.

Comment: There is not enought inforfation to help with this problem, Can you attach the file and FBX Export settings screenshot, please.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today. I traced it down to one image texture. Once, I used a different for testing. The problem didnt occur again

Comment: uv_id in the errors gave me the hint.

Comment: please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/191929/edit) any additional information relating to answer into answer.